# Transformation throws error when output is surrounded by curly braces

Tags: dataweave

I am new to Dataweave, following transformation is throwing error:

```
"Invalid input '.', expected Namespace (line 5, column 8):".
```

Why does putting "{ }" around "payload.message" throw this error?

Input:

```
{
    "message": "Hello world!"
}
```

Dataweave Transformation:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
 payload.message
}
```

Comment: What is the output that you expected when you added the curly braces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In DataWeave curly braces delimit an object, which is a collection of key-values pairs. In your script the key is missing.

Example of a correct transformation by adding a key named `message`:

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
    message: payload.message
}
```

Output:

```json
{
    "message": "Hello world!"
}
```

Comment: Thanks @aled, I just realize the issue and came to delete the question but you had already answered.

Comment: It maybe useful to others that have the same error message.